# Как вернуть картинку ajax'ом? Вернее, что с этим делать

Tags: jquery, ajax, изображения

Есть php-скрипт, кторорый возвращает gif-изображение (капча). Выглядит, примерно так:

```
<img src='folder/script.php?param=pararam'>
```

Хочу сделать ajax-обновление картинки. Но скрипт возвращает именно содержимое файла-изображения. Т.е. набор символов.

Как сделать, чтобы возвращаемое нечто можно было использовать как изображение?

P.S. Если просто вставить в html - все работает. А как полученную аяксом инфу представить в виде изображения - не понимаю.

Comment: Заголовки выводите перед тем как файл вывести?

Comment: Не совсем уверен, что правильно понял, но есть такое:
header('Expires: Sat, 17 May 2008 05:00:00 GMT'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE); 
header('Pragma: no-cache');
Зачем и почему - не знаю)

Comment: Это чтобы кеширования небыло. Должны быть заголовки которые скажут браузеру что этот файл это картинка. Например если это png то нужно к заголовкам добавить тажке

header("Content-type: image/png");

Comment: header("Content-type: image/png") тоже есть. Я ж говорю - если адрес скрипта прописать как адрес изображения, все ок. А если вызываю ajax'ом то возвращается содержимое изображения. В принципе это логично.

Comment: Тогда думаю что в данном случае будет удобно сохранять картинку на сервере и возвращать только урл на нее после чего вставлять урл в src.

Comment: Ну... тоже верно. Но муторно)
 Я думал, можно всю эту ахинею как-то запихнуть в объект img.

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov в принципе можно, читайте про base64 src в примерно таком формате src src="data:image/png;base64" ещё можно отрисовать его в canvas и сослаться на blob в src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочу сделать ajax-обновление картинки. Но скрипт возвращает именно содержимое файла-изображения. Т.е. набор символов.

Пропишите адрес скрипта которое возвращает именно содержимое файла-изображение в src. Если адрес не меняется, делайте так, чтобы эта картинка не кэшировалась.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы не кэшировалась?

Comment: как вариант добавить заголовки:

    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Content-type: image/png");

или как ниже написали, дописать к тому запросу случайное число в параметр: 

    <img src='image.php?picid=10&rnd=<?php print time(); ?> '>

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы изображение вернулось не кешированное , нужно помимо указания заголовков в скрипте, который выдает изображение в ссылке на скрипт передавать случайное значение! тогда скрипт будет считать это новой ссылкой и будет генерить новое изображение

```
folder/script.php?param=pararam&random=8129837128372198
```